# SSAS Cube in Excel - Show only applicable rows with KPI?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, excel

I have a cube built in SSAS 2008r2.  I'm exposing it for the moment through an excel PivotTable.

I recently added a KPI to the cube, and when I show the KPI in my PivotTable interface it causes non-applicable dimension values to be shown at the current level.

For instance, suppose I have customers:

```
CustomerA
CustomerB
CustomerC
```

And States:

```
NY
VA
TX
```

When I look at the PivotTable without the KPI, `CustomerB` has no rows under `NY` because they have no locations there.

When I add my KPI in and display just the `value` of the KPI, all is well.

When I add in the status indicator (i.e. traffic light or whatever),  **I see every customer under every state.**

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way around it?  I like the KPI but it defeats the purpose if I get every value of my dimension at each level.

Some more details:

The `Value Expression` for the KPI is just a calculated measure, which works fine.

The `Status Expression` is:

```
CASE
    WHEN KpiValue("MyKPI") / KpiGoal("MyKPI") > .90
        THEN 1
    WHEN KpiValue("MyKPI") / KpiGoal("MyKPI") <= .90
        AND KpiValue("MyKPI") / KpiGoal("MyKPI") > .75
    THEN 0
ELSE -1
END
```

Comment: That's weird, it shouldn't do that. Do you make a complicated MDX to calculate your KPI?

Comment: @Lamak not super complicated. I posted the code.

Comment: @Lamak Is there maybe some MDX to filter to only show rows that are applicable at the current level?

Comment: I was actually trying to do the same, and I was able to  replicate the behaviour you are obtaining, so now I'm trying to understand what is happening here

Comment: @Lamak well its nice to know it's not just me, and that you understand the issue.  I am new to SSAS so I worried by misuse of terminology might complicate troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells for pointing me in the right direction on this.

The issue was with the status expression.

Since it ALWAYS returns a `1`, `0` or `-1` it didn't account for `NULL`s.

I added a check at the beginning of the expression:

`CASE WHEN IsEmpty(KpiValue("MyKPI")) THEN NULL`

...which correctly leaves  those fields empty.